# Can I get the ID of the data that I just inserted?

Tags: c#, sql, database

So I want to put a product in an order from an user in the database and the query goes as follows:

`INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order](UserID, To_Adress, OrderDate, TravelTime, ItemCount, Status, TotalPrice) 
VALUES (1, 'BIKINI BOTTOM', '20191030 15:00:00', '20191030 15:35:00', 1, 'InTheMaking', 7.50)`

After I put in the order I want to put the connection between the product and the order in the database but I have to get the `OrderID` that I just made. Is there a way to get the `OrderID` from the order that I just made?

`INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Product](OrderID, ProductID)
 VALUES (?[dbo].[Order].OrderID?, 12)`

EDIT:

Okay, so basically `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is the way to get it out of my database, but how do I use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in a second `INSERT` while still being in the same query? Do I just have to make 2 seperate queries for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last inserted row ID (with SQL statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement)

Comment: I think you will find your answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert

Comment: Where does order ID come from? You should storage it in a variable and then use it in both querys. And alternative way that may work is to do the query "SELECT OrderId FROM [dbo],[Order] LIMIT 1", which generally returns last record added

Comment: you can try `@@identity`.  `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Product](OrderID, ProductID)  VALUES (@@identity, 12)`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, OrderId is a sequence or a serial or something that autoincrements, and you not give it a value on INSERT. I would recommend you not to do that. Instead, before INSERT, run a "SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[order]", add 1 to that, and use that number as your orderId in INSERT.

Comment: @Cid Okay so `SCOPE_IDENTITY` would get the last `OrderID` how would I be able to immediately use it in the other table `Order_Product`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: @CR0N0S.LXIII that is horrible and wide open to concurrency issues. The database should assign the ID itself.

Comment: @KrishnaMohanVarma How would I declare it? With `@@ID.SCOPE_IDENTITY`?

Comment: @BugFinder Well...partially....i know how to get it and return it now but i still want to use the ID to insert it in a second query.

Comment: Well if you have have the variables you should be able to use them in the next query

Comment: @BugFinder But there's no way to do it in one go?

Comment: it doesnt feel like youve done much googling - have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534500/using-identity-or-output-when-inserting-into-sql-server-view

Comment: @BugFinder Well...I'm still a really big novice at coding and stuff, but thanks for the help :P

Answer (score 2):

Try using the SQL [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order](UserID, To_Adress, OrderDate, TravelTime, ItemCount, Status, TotalPrice)
OUTPUT inserted.ID
VALUES (1, 'BIKINI BOTTOM', '20191030 15:00:00', '20191030 15:35:00', 1, 'InTheMaking', 7.50
```

In combination with [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8)