# Using auto assigned primary key or setting it on INSERT?

Tags: sql

I just answered this question: [Can I get the ID of the data that I just inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728374/can-i-get-the-id-of-the-data-that-i-just-inserted#comment103748008_58728374). I explained that in order to know the ID of the last record inserted in a table, what I would do is inserting it manually, instead of using some sequence or serial field.

What I like to do is to run a Max(id) query before INSERT, add 1 to that result, and use that number as ID for the record I'm about to insert.

Now, what I would like to ask: is this a good idea? Can it give some trouble? What are the reasons to use automatically set field on IDs fields?

Note: this is not exactly a question, but looking help center it seems like a good question to ask. If you find it to be off-topic, please tell me and I'll remove it.

Comment: Running a `max(id)` is a really bad idea. This won't work if you have concurrent transactions (because all see the same value for the max()) - plus it's horribly inefficient. Using a sequence or an identity column is the most efficient and scalable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea and **it will fail** in a multi threaded (or multi users) environment.

Please note that the [surrogate-key vs natural-key](https://www.google.com/search?q=surrogate%20key%20vs%20natural%20key&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=surrogate%20key%20vs%20natural%20key%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8519j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) debate is still far from having a concrete definitive solution - but putting that aside for a minute - even if you do go with a surrogate key - you should never try to manually auto-increment columns. Let the database do that for you and avoid all kinds of problems that can occur if you try to do that manually - such as primary key constraint violations in the best case, or duplicate values in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

If an Entity uses an ID as the Primary-Key, it is in general a good idea to let the DB autocreate it, so you don't need to determine an unused one while creating this Entity in your code. Furthermore a DateAccessObject(DAO) does not need to operate on the ID.
Dependant on what DB u might use, you might even not be allowed to retrieve all IDs of that Table..

I guess there might be other good reasons to let the DB manage this part.