# Must declare scalar variable '@ID' with OUTPUT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, database

I get this error, but I thought i declared it already. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
DECLARE @ID TABLE(OrderID INT)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order](UserID, To_Adress, OrderDate, TravelTime, ItemCount, Status, TotalPrice) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.OrderID INTO @ID
VALUES (1, 'BIKINI BOTTOM', '20191030 15:00:00', '20191030 15:35:00', 1, 'InTheMaking', 7.50) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Product](OrderID, ProductID) VALUES (@ID, 12)
```

Background: So basically I tried to get the auto-incremented ID that I just inserted and tried to implement the `DECLARE` `OUTPUT` 
 method instead of the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`-way from the comment from BugFinder. [Can I get the ID of the data that I just inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728374/can-i-get-the-id-of-the-data-that-i-just-inserted?noredirect=1#comment103751083_58728374)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a `FROM` clause, because the value is in a table:

```
DECLARE @IDS TABLE (OrderID INT);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order](UserID, To_Adress, OrderDate, TravelTime, ItemCount, Status, TotalPrice) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OrderID INTO @IDS
    VALUES (1, 'BIKINI BOTTOM', '20191030 15:00:00', '20191030 15:35:00', 1, 'InTheMaking', 7.50);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Product](OrderID, ProductID) 
    SELECT i.OrderID, 12
    FROM @IDS i;
```

I changed the name to `@IDS` to make it clear that it can have more than one row.

Comment: Question: why did the second `INSERT` changed to `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` because I still want that OrderID filled in the `[Order_Product]` table

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai . . . Because `VALUES()` doesn't have a `FROM` clause to refer to `@IDS`.

Comment: Oooohhh, sorry my bad...I didn't find the connection between the insert and select. Damn I've never thought of using `INSERT` and `SELECT` that way :o

Comment: This might not be related but the two ID's in `Order_Product` make together the primary key, so if there were another column `ItemAmount` and it would increment every time this query gets used, how would you do it? Because it's seems almost impossible to do it in one query.

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai . . . You can use `row_number()` in the `select` used for the `insert`.